# .NET: Determine whether object is partially or fully constructed

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

Is there any way to query the .NET runtime to determine whether an object has finished its construction, or if the construction is still on-going and/or was aborted with an exception?

Basically, something equivalent to:

```
class Foo {
    public string ConstructionState { get; private set; }

    public Foo() {
        try {
            ConstructionState = "ongoing";

            // ... do actual constructor stuff here ...

            ConstructionState = "completed";
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            ConstructionState = "aborted";
            throw;
        }    
    }
}
```

... except also taking into account field initializers, base class constructors etc., and without needing to modify the constructor.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve by being able to observe the state?

Comment: I would expect the example you provided to work... does it not?

Comment: In what context? This is pretty obviously not possible to do in a thread-safe manner. If you are in some nested virtual call of the object, you may get somewhere by walking the stack, but the big question would be what you could hope to achieve, other than some rather expensive sanity checks.

Comment: A call to `new C()` will not return until the constructor has finished, if an exception is thrown (and not caught) then it will be propagated to the caller. If the object could not be allocated the operator will throw `OutOfMemoryException`. What part of this behavior is insufficient?

Comment: @McGuireV10: My example works, except for the part where it doesn't take into account field initializers, base class constructors etc., and where it requires the constructor to be modified. :-) Imagine that the class isn't mine.

Comment: Note that neither field initializers nor base class constructors are "special", in that all of that code ends up in the constructor. It may not read that way in a source file, but the compiler will move all inline field initializers to the constructor, followed by the base constructor call, followed by whatever code you explicitly put in the constructor. On the IL level, rewriting the constructor to do something at the beginning and the end is certainly possible. A profiler can do such rewriting at runtime, even. This isn't something you'd do on a whim, though.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert: I'm not sure what thread-safety has to do with anything. The runtime is perfectly able to provide a thread-safe "is eligible for finalization" bit for every object. I'm asking if there's a similar "is-fully-constructed" bit exposed somewhere.

Comment: My point is that asking "is this object fully constructed *now*" has obvious synchronization issues, if you did it from another thread, and you cared about seeing "no". ("Yes" would be stable, if your intent was waiting on that.) The runtime itself can of course implement anything it likes as it has full control over everything, from threads down to the GC.

Comment: @SørenLøvborg I still wonder what problem you're trying to solve, because all I can think of is a class that stores its `this` somewhere _during_ construction, and another thread stumbling upon it. Which would call for a different design rather than "have you finished?" polling.

Comment: I take it from the number of tangential comments that the answer to my actual question is likely "no". In which case I'll deliberate my problem and may come back with another, less specific question. :-)

Comment: Without having dug as deep as possible into the reference source, I'm willing to tentatively put out there that the answer is going to be "no", simply because I can't even think of an instance where the runtime *itself* needs to know this, beyond *maybe* the allocator, and even then only temporarily. Specifically, partially constructed objects are still collectable (and finalizable), methods can be called on them, etc. There is never a place where it needs to check to avoid doing something (or raise a meaningful error condition), so why record it, let alone in a public place?

Comment: @M.Aroosi The partially constructed object can easily be leaked outside of the constructor, you don't need to wait for it to return. You have `this` inside the constructor. And it gets even more fragile once you call any virtual method inside the constructor (or really, any instance method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A well-behaved object should never expose itself until it's fully constructed. If a partially constructed object is leaked, you're already violating that contract.

The runtime doesn't care, of course. There's nothing special about a partially-constructed object as far as the runtime is concerned - it's still subject to the same memory constraints, finalization and garbage collection as a fully constructed object.

If you own the object, the solution is simple - don't leak the object during construction. The usual way to do some global change during object initialisation is to use a static method (or a factory) instead of a constructor. If you don't own the object, you're pretty much out of luck.

The runtime specification doesn't explicitly say there's no way to check if an object is partially constructed, but it doesn't say there is either (as far as I can tell) - so even if you found some way, it wouldn't be safe to rely on it. Inspecting by hand shows that .NET object headers have no such information, and a disassembly of the constructor shows there's no non-user code after a constructor finishes that could update such a state.

The runtime does store a few flags in "weird" places. The mark & sweep garbage collector in desktop MS.NET stores its marks in an "unused" bit of the pointer to the virtual method table, for example. But as far as the runtime is concerned, the object is "done" even before any of its constructors run - all of that is handled during the allocation in `newobj`, before the constructor (a special instance method) runs. The object header (which also contains the object size) and virtual method table (so the object is of the most derived type even before the constructors run) are already set here, and all the memory directly used by that instance is already allocated (and pre-zeroed - so you don't get pointers to random bits of memory). This means that memory safety isn't impacted by partially-constructed objects *as far as the runtime is concerned*.

The main difference between a constructor and another instance method is that the constructor must only ever be called once on any instance. On the CIL level, this is enforced simply by the fact that you can't invoke the constructor directly - you only ever use `newobj`, which pushes the constructed object on the stack. Just like with other instance methods, it doesn't track if a particular method finishes or not - after all, it's perfectly legal to have  a method that *never* finishes, and you can actually do the same thing with a (non-static) constructor.

If you want a proof that the runtime doesn't care, I present to you... the object can be collected by the GC *before the constructor even finishes*:

```
class Test
{
    public static WeakReference<Test> someInstance;

    public static void AliveTest()
    {
        Test t;
        if (someInstance == null) Console.WriteLine("Null");
        else Console.WriteLine(someInstance.TryGetTarget(out t));
    }

    public Test()
    {
        someInstance = new WeakReference<Test>(this);

        AliveTest();

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

        AliveTest();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        Test.AliveTest();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This test program writes out True, False, False (make sure to run it in Release mode and without the debugger - .NET prevents many things like this to make debugging easier). The object has been collected before its constructor even finished, which means that there's no special treatment for constructors in this regard. Another reason not to use the "constructor updates something static" pattern, and especially not the "finalizer updates it back". If you add a finalizer to this sample code, it will run before the constructor finishes. Ouch.

Even your solution would be insufficient in the general case. To cite CLI specification:

> It is explicitly not a requirement that a conforming implementation of the CLI guarantee that all state updates performed within a constructor be uniformly visible before the constructor completes.

There's no guarantee another thread would have correct information about the construction state.

For bonus points, it also doesn't help if the object isn't sealed. A derived classes constructor would run *after* the base class constructor and in C# there's no way to rewrite this to encompass *all* the constructors that normally run in a sequence. The best you could do is maintain a separate "constructed state" for each constructor, which is confusing at best (and breaks a few OOP principles - it would require all consumers of the object to know of all possible types the object could have).

Comment: I see that `Main` can even invoke methods on `t` (being a reference to an object that _does not exist_), provided the method isn't virtual and doesn't access member fields. Nice optimization.